# Azure sql sessions stay in sleeping status when dockerized dotnet core 1.1. app deployed to Azure Web App

Tags: .net-core

I have an dotnet core 1.1. application with identityserver 4 and it was deployed to Azure App service and was working fine. However, in some point, the web app stopped working. We had to options; one upgrading the dotnet core version to the newer version (because app service doesn't support older version) or we had to dockerize the app (with 1.1. version) and deploy it to web app with docker image. We implemented the second option, basically I created a dockerfile, build the image, push it to registry, and deployed to new azure web app. It was working fine but then one day it throw an exception which related to session count and when we check the database connections from sql server, we saw that some sessions stay pending status.

This problem didn't happen when we deployed the app without docker. However, the session count in database increases every day because we deploy the app with docker. We don't understand if the docker open this database session itself (and don't close it) or it is the dbContext causes this problem.